# libmysqlclient.a for armv7s

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How can I get the libmysqlclient.a for armv7s so I can use it for my iPhone 5 to? Now I get this error:

```
ld: file is universal (6 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/x/Documents/Xcode/Projecten/DirectMySQL/DirectMySQL/Objc_Mysql_iPhone_OSX/lib/libmysqlclient.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks,

Daan!

Comment: If you can not find a ARMv7s build of the library you could also remove support for the ARMv7s from your project. Your will still run fine on the iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the armv7s from the architecture build settings. This is not necessary for anything other than high performance games on the iPhone 5 processor. Apple's default project include the armv7s but you don't need it.